# How to host Flutter Web (Hummingbird) on Firebase Hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I created a flutter web project and work fine in localhost. So I planned to host the website in firebase. I followed the commands it deployed successfully but it shows only black screen in the console it shows error message.

Error :

Loading failed for the  with source “https://myportfolioflutterweb.firebaseapp.com/web/main.dart.js”.
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]

My Project Structure :

[image]

firebase.json :

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [
    {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "/web/index.html",
      "type": 302
    }
  ]
  }
}
```

Commands:

[image]

Note: When I give public dir as the public folder it creates index.html. I deleted the file manually and navigate to the path as web/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue. I navigate the wrong path in public folder on firebase hosting. To deploy flutter web first I need to build the project using below command

**Build**

```
webdev build
```

After I build the project It creates a build folder inside the project
[image]
Before I public path as root but the correct path is build

**Correct Path:**

```
 What do you want to use as your public directory? build
```

I attached full command of firebase hosting deployment below,

[image]

Comment: Your other mistake was to configure this as a single page app. It won't find any assets you might have.