# The same Flutter web build runs locally with `dhttp` but fails with `firebase serve` or `firebase deploy`

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I'm developing a Flutter app for both mobile and web. It uses several packages, including those for Firestore:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+1 #imported conditionally for mobile
  firebase_web: ^5.0.9 #imported conditionally for web
  #firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1 #not sure whether it's required in my case, assuming not (?)
```

My `web/index.html` includes the following scripts:

```
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

1) The app works as expected in debug mode.

2) Then I make a build with `flutter build web` with the resulting file structure similar to those from [the tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release).

2.1) It works as expected when I run it locally with [dhttpd](https://pub.dev/packages/dhttpd) `flutter pub global run dhttpd --path build/web`

3) Then I'm trying to deploy it to Firebase hosting.

When running `firebase init` I set `build/web` as **a public directory**. At first I was confused by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206091/how-to-host-flutter-web-hummingbird-on-firebase-hosting) that it should be just `build` but I assume it was true for the preview version of Flutter for web, and now it's `build/web` where `index.html` lives.

As for configuring as **a single-page app** (rewrite all urls to /index.html) I tried both yes/no with no visible difference. Again a small confusion from the comment to the answer from the link above: *"Your other mistake was to configure this as a single page app. It won't find any assets you might have."*

3.1) Firstly, trying it out locally following [the tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying#test-locally)  `firebase serve` or `firebase serve --only hosting` - both of them gives me an empty page with the background of the correct color from the defined theme, but with nothing else present. In page inspector and sources tab I see all the same html structure and scripts loaded as in step (2.1), with the only difference being the extra directories `assetes` and `__/firebase` in case of Firebase.

[image: firebase serve local results]

3.2) Trying to `firebase deploy` results in the same empty background screen as in (3.1). There's no errors to investigate in the `firebase-debug.log`. Which other logs should I look into?

*(using Flutter latest version master v1.13.3-pre.12, Firebase tools v7.10.0)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the order of including the scripts in `web/index.html`. Placing the `/__/firebase/init.js` foremost solved it:

```
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Thanks to @emanuel-muroni for leading me to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to modify your `web/index.html`

**from**

```
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

**to**

```
<script defer src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

This way the "main.dart.js" script is executed when the page has finished parsing

Comment: Thank you so much Emanuel! Although your suggested solution (only `defer`ing `main.dart.js`) itself didn't work, it led me to `defer`ing all scripts except for `/__/firebase/init.js` and that worked. Moreover, it actually works without `defer`s at all, with the correct order so that initializing goes first.

Comment: Thank you so much Emanuel !!!!!!! "defer" literally saved my day! My situation is that my flutter web runs fine with 'flutter run -d chrome'. But when i run it with 'firebase --debug emulators:start' OR 'dhttpd --port 8888', it will show 'Page not Found' error on google chrome and my text fields were all disabled. Error logging didnt help much either. To whomever is seeing this, i hope Emanuel's answer is able to help you. Because it definitely helped me a tonne.  Thanks again <3